# Instagram (unofficial) API returning 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, instagram-api

I have been working my way through the Unofficial [Instagram-API-python](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python)
and (in short) what my app did was to download **public** data (likes per photo) of various Instagram users.
After about 24 hours of work suddenly I received the following message

```
code of 400 (Bad Request)
```

After checking out the rate limits on the official Instagram API [page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/), I found out that this `400 Bad Request` is not linked to limits, but to `"spammy"` behaviour.

From documentation:

```
"You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting."
```

There are similar questions on stack overflow, but none of them seem to provide any solutions.
My questions are:

1. Does anyone know what is defined as spammy behavior (not the exact formula, but an intuitive explanation)?
2. Is there around this (through the unofficial API)?
3. It seems to be unrelated whether it's through the unofficial API or sandbox mode / live mode in the official API, so there must be something that people who have created reliable apps off Instagram's API, take into account when constructing their request behavior.

P.S. note that in the documentation, it's explicitly noted that this is not related to the request frequency.

P.S.2 48 hours lated my account could run the same code and there `400 Bad Request` was gone, so it was a temporary ban.

Any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: how are u calling the API, which API, what does your app do ?

Comment: My app downloads the user data (such as number of followers and likes per photo for the user and its followers) and I am calling it through the Instagram-API-python link provided in the question (this is an unofficial API).